# Galaxy S3 Can't boot to teamwin recovery

Tags: cyanogenmod

I'm trying to Install CyanogenMod on my Samsung Galaxy S III, while using this guide
http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_i9300

For that end I need to install a new recovery mode.

Everything seem to work fine, until I'm trying Manually reboot the phone into recovery mode, the newly teamwin recovery( (Flashed with heimdall ), when I try that (holding vol up+powr+home in the download mode after flashing the new recovery mode) it gets me to "downloading do not turn off target" screen. if I reboot and try again the "vol up+powr+home", this time it gets me to the stock rom recovery.

How can I boot to the teamwin recovery after flashing it with heimdall ???

I have GT-I9300 with stock Android 4.3 not rooted!

Comment: Flash again and this time boot directly into recovery. Don't let the OS have a chance to overwrite it.

Comment: I did tried boot directly into recovery after done flashing, while i'm in the odin  "download mode" and yet it does not boot to the  teamwin recovery mode, instead it boots to  "downloading do not turn off target" screen...

Comment: This is where it gets me
http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=nycgjygeoz3z.jpg

Comment: Post your solution as an answer yourself, and mark it as accepted. That'll be of use to others later.

Comment: ..,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Answer (score -2):

Problem solved. Full Process to the solution can be found [at AndroidForums](http://androidforums.com/threads/cant-boot-to-teamwin-recovery.1062216/). Basically, it seems it was a broken download (image file corrupted): I downloaded a fresh image [from twrp.me](https://dl.twrp.me/i9300/twrp-3.0.2-1-i9300.img.html) and repeated the installation process, now everything works.

Comment: Thanks for self-answering the issue – but please, do as beeshyams suggested.